# Snap svg multiple animations - performance issues

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, svg, snap.svg

This is my first attempt animating SVG using javascript/jquery/snap, and I've discovered the animations don't run very well on even some quite recent devices (testing on iPhone 4s). Seems like a performance issue?

I'm trying to animate a number of grouped elements in a svg that's embedded into my html. They animate on page load, here's the relevant code.

Note: my svg was drawn in illustrator at the 'end' state of the animations, so I've offset them using snap and then animated back to their natural positions

```
$(function() {
    //initialise renderer
    var renderer = Snap(".bg-space_svg");

    //define animation start states
    var stars_bg_transform = new Snap.Matrix().translate(0, 200).scale(1.5, 1.5, 260, 0);
    var shard_center_transform = new Snap.Matrix().translate(0, 80).scale(1.8, 1.8, 260, 0);
    var shard_left_transform = new Snap.Matrix().translate(-45, 30).scale(1.3, 1.3, 220, 0);
    var shard_right_transform = new Snap.Matrix().translate(50, 40).scale(1.3, 1.3, 300, 0).rotate(-16);
    var stars_center_transform = new Snap.Matrix().translate(0, -80).scale(0.8, 0.8, 260, 0);
    var stars_left_transform = new Snap.Matrix().translate(-70, -30).scale(0.7, 0.7, 220, 0);
    var stars_right_transform = new Snap.Matrix().translate(80, -30).scale(0.7, 0.7, 300, 0).rotate(-16);

    //capture svg elements in variables
    var greenline = renderer.select('.green-line');
    var starsbg = renderer.select('.stars-background').transform(stars_bg_transform);
    var shard_center = renderer.select('.shard-center').transform(shard_center_transform).attr({'fill-opacity': 0.8});
    var shard_left = renderer.select('.shard-left').transform(shard_left_transform);
    var shard_right = renderer.select('.shard-right').transform(shard_right_transform);
    var stars_center = renderer.select('.stars-center').transform(stars_center_transform);
    var stars_left = renderer.select('.stars-left').transform(stars_left_transform);
    var stars_right = renderer.select('.stars-right').transform(stars_right_transform);

    //define original positions of svg elements as a "null" transform - this is the end state of the animations
    var origin = new Snap.Matrix().translate(0, 0).scale(1);

    //initialise animations
    starsbg.animate({'transform': origin}, 3000, mina.easeinout);
    shard_center.animate({'transform': origin, 'fill-opacity': 1}, 3000, mina.easeinout);
    shard_left.animate({'transform': origin}, 3000, mina.easeinout);
    shard_right.animate({'transform': origin}, 3000, mina.easeinout);
    stars_center.animate({'transform': origin}, 3000, mina.easeinout);
    stars_left.animate({'transform': origin}, 3000, mina.easeinout);
    stars_right.animate({'transform': origin}, 3000, mina.easeinout);
    greenline.animate({'stroke-opacity': 1}, 1000);
});
```

What happens is that the start state initialises fine, but the animations themselves don't run and simply pop to the end state after a few seconds of lag.

Is there perhaps a better way to handle these animations so that they perform a bit better?

Do I perhaps need to write a custom draw loop and then call this using requestAnimationFrame or something similar? (I'm very new to this concept, help!)

Comment: Possible to pop the same svg along with code on a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

If you still are interested in this matter, I ran into a similar issue with Snap that might be related.  The library doesn't officially support passing a matrix in as a transform argument to animate() only transform().  It usually works but sometimes not and sometimes tweens from the wrong data if you do.  So until they address this in the library, you need to replace calls of the form:

```
// if origin is a matrix and not a string
starsbg.animate({'transform': origin}, 3000, mina.easeinout);
// replace with this
starsbg.animate({'transform': origin.toTransformString() }, 3000, mina.easeinout);
```